# Wordpress site dropdown menu suddenly stopped working

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I've tried searching the forums about this but I can't find something that works in my case.

I'm using elementor with Wordpress and Astra themes. For some reason suddenly the dropdown menu disappears fast when you try and click the menus. The dropdown menu also goes behind the pictures on some of the pages (not the front page). I have not edited anything about the menu and I have no idea how it happened.

Here it shows what I mean with the menu going behind the pictures

[image]
It does not do this on the front page.

The website is https://www.onebag.dk/

Does anybody know how I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top *elementor* HTML element...

```
<div data-elementor-type="product-archive" data-elementor-id="589" 
class="elementor elementor-589 elementor-location-archive product" data- 
elementor-settings="[]">
```

... is positioned relatively but has no z-index set.

If you set the z-index below 9999 (the index of the submenu) it works. I think you can use this css in the custom css section of your theme:

```
div.elementor {
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Maybe this is a bug in the theme, or it is a conflict between theme and a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I used this custom CSS to fix the problem:

```
#masthead {
    z-index:99999
}

#content {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Basicly, made index of header higher than contents index and worked.